# NixOS: unique ID for a flake configuration based on source code

Tags: nixos

I have a Flake-based NixOS configuration.
I need some unique identifier for each built this configuration produces, i.e if a configuration gets changed the identifier changes.

This is what I have in my `configuration.nix`

```
  environment.etc."version".text = builtins.readFile
    (pkgs.runCommand "version" {
      nativeBuildInputs = [ pkgs.coreutils pkgs.util-linux ];
    } ''test -d ${./} && uuidgen > "$out"'');
```

This unfortunately will copy the entire configuration directory to `/nix/store`.
Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: Dependencies of any derivation need to be in nix store.  That will be hard to avoid.

Comment: Nix typically moves stuff to the nix store yes. But there is a WIP to allow nix flake to work also for cases where you do not want to copy everything to the store (e.g. during development time), that you can find here https://github.com/NixOS/nix/issues/3121 Not sure how it relates to you specific issue without knowing more.